# Programmatically Load Assembly From Local Nuget Package File

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget, console-application

On my local file System I have the nuget package `foo.nupkg`. It contains the assembly `foo.dll`.

If I manually extract the `foo.nupkg` I can programmatically load the `foo.dll` assembly as follows:

```
AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath("c:/path/foo.dll");
```

**How can I load the assembly from `foo.nupkg` directly?**

What I already tried:

- Of course I can programmatically extract the `.nupkg` file to a temporary directory but I wonder if this is really required.
- I tried using package `NuGet.Core`. I provides a `PackageManager#InstallPackage` that accepts an `IPackage`. But it seems that `IPackage` instances can only be revtrieved from repositories (which I don't have).

Answer (score 4):

A nuget package is just a zip file, so you could simply use System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive to read it.

You can also load an assembly from a byte array, so something like this should work (assuming newtonsoft.json package is in the working directory):

```
using var archive = ZipFile.OpenRead("newtonsoft.json.12.0.3.nupkg");
var entry = archive.GetEntry("lib/netstandard2.0/Newtonsoft.Json.dll");

using var target = new MemoryStream();

using var source = entry.Open();
source.CopyTo(target);

var assembly = Assembly.Load(target.ToArray());
var type = assembly.GetType("Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert");
Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
```